# How to fix special Failed to load resource problems

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a jQuery code that sends data(title, cover, body of article) to the server for upload. The issue I have is the server responds with a console error: **"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()"** for certain changes with data transfer.  By my observation, the "body" textarea is what triggers this issue. For certain body of text, there is no error. But, for others, the 403() error comes up.

I know what 403 means, directly. But, why return 403 **sometimes** when I try some kind of text and don't for other text. This only works with the *body* textarea element: `<textarea id="ft-body" class="ft-body" name="notes" placeholder="What\'s on your mind?"></textarea>`

This is the jQuery upload code:

```
$(e).on("click",function(i){
    t(!0,".5");
    var o = function(e,t,k,l) {
        var n = $("form").get(0),
            a = new FormData(n);

            return a.append("the_body_textarea",e),
            a.append("the_title",t),
            a.append('images',k),
            a.append('which_editor',l),
            a
    }($("#body").val(), $("#title").val(), imagesAdded, whichEditor);
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '../manager.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: o,
        xhr:function(){
            var e = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            e.upload && e.upload.addEventListener("progress", n, !1); //progress function is not shown.
            return e
        },
        contentType: !1,
        cache: !1,
        processData: !1,
        success: function(n){
            !function(n){
                ("10" === n.trim()) ? 
                (a("Success","mediumseagreen"), t(!0,".5"), i="handler.php", $(location).attr("href",i)) : 
                (a(n),t(!1,"1"), e.text("Retry"));
            }(n)
        },
        error: function(n,i,o){
            a("Funny error. Retry.","tomato"),
            t(!1,"1"),
            e.text("SUBMIT"),
            console.error(o)
        }
    }),
    i.preventDefault()
})
```

I use PHP for my backend.

UPDATE: I used a new hosting server and it works fine. It turns out it was the server that was preventing the upload, not from my code.

Comment: The server that you're sending the data to is under your control? That's where your problem lies, and what you'll need to debug to find why it's sending a 403.

Comment: Yes, the server is under my control.

Comment: Then it's your code that's generating the 403 error. That's what you need to fix.

Comment: It might also be some server firewall, that tries to block requests it thinks might be cross-site scripting attempts.

Comment: 'Cross-site scripting attempts' that makes sense. Let me check to find.

Comment: It doesn't work. The server keeps rejecting the textarea value. When I comment out send the textraea value to the server, it works. But, when I bring it back, it returns 403() error. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Have you looked at what your server code does with the textarea data? For example, are you wrapping the text in single quotes in an INSERT statement, but not accounting for the fact that the incoming text might have a single quote in it that would break the query?

Comment: The funny thing is the server code doesn't even catch the jQuery's POST request. It's blank on the server side. If I do an IF ISSET $_POST[], I don't capture anything. 
Even an ELSE after the IF still doesn't capture anything. The only response I get is the one jQuery gives me from the console.error(o) statement. I find it amusing.

Comment: I am currently setting up another server with a different hosting company. (Not done migrating the code.) I want to see if it's something particular to the hosting server or my code. If it works with the new server, then it's not my code. I will use the exact same image, the same article title, and the same article body to confirm.